# Open facebox from c# codebehind

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, facebox

I am creating a basic contact us form that contains a few fields and a button. I am using the jquery facebox plugin which I want to open after the buttons click event is fired displaying a value from one of the textboxes within the div tag.

e.g.

```
<div id="info" style="display:none;"><h1>Thanks for your enquiry</h1><p>Thanks [NAMEFIELD],<br /> Someone will be in contact with you shortly.</p>
```

Any tips would be great!

Comment: could you clarify your question? Is there a problem with the facebox documentation you don't understand?

Answer (score 0):

Well.. I can be wrong here... 
But your initialization code looks like this, right?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('a[rel*=facebox]').facebox() 
})
```

Why don't you emulate the click of your anchor?

like

```
$('#contactUs').click();
```

after the facebox initialization (still inside document ready).

**EDIT:**

If you really want the "server-side" of things you can have a method to insert the javascript to trigger the click from it.